# Factorizing and non-factorizing morphisms between same objects

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading Category Theory for Programmers and this particular fragment from chapter about cones and limits has really puzzled me:

"For every other cone we have a unqiue factorizing morphism that maps its apex, let's call it $c$, to the apex of the universal cone, which we named $\textbf{Lim}D$. Let me repeat the important part: given any cone, there is a unique morphism of a special kind. WE have a mapping of cones to special morphisms, and it's a one-to-one mapping.

This special morphism is a member of the hom-set $C(c, \textbf{Lim}D)$. The other members of this hom-set are less fortunate, in the sense that they don't factorize the mapping of cones."

From my understanding hom-set may be empty in case of absence of morphisms between objects, and it can have multiple morphisms. But how can they differ? Aren't they supposed to be the same? Or one morphism going from object $a$ and $b$ does factorize some other morphisms, but another going from the same object to the same endpoint does not which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the complete definition of what this "special morphism" is.

Comment: For every cone we have unique factorizing morphism that maps its apex, let's call it $c$ which we named  $\textbf{Lim}D$. So this special morphism for every cone is the one that goes from its apex ( $c$ ) to apex of the universal cone if i'm getting it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author considers  a *diagram* in $\pmb C$ which is a functor $\pmb D : \pmb I \to \pmb C$, where $\pmb I$ is an index category, and introduces the concept of a *cone over $\pmb D$*. A cone $\Gamma$ over $\pmb D$ is nothing else than a system consisting of an object $\pmb c$ of $\pmb C$ and a morphism $\gamma_i : \pmb c \to \pmb D(i)$ for each object $i$ of $\pmb I$  such that $\pmb D(\varphi) \circ \gamma_i = \gamma_j$ for all morphisms $\varphi : i \to j$ in $\pmb I$. We  write $\Gamma = (\pmb c,(\gamma_i))$. The object $\pmb c$ is called the *apex of $\Gamma$* and we write $\pmb c = \pmb a(\Gamma)$.

Given any object $\pmb c'$ and any morphism $\mu : \pmb c' \to \pmb c$ in $\pmb C$, we obtain a cone denoted by $\Gamma \circ \mu$ which is given as $(\pmb c', (\gamma_i \circ \mu)$. Its apex is $\pmb c'$.

It is possible that not every object $\pmb c$ in $\pmb C$ occurs as an apex of a cone, but that is irrelevant here.

A *universal cone over $\pmb D$* is defined as a terminal object in the category $\mathfrak{Cone}_{\pmb D}$ of all cones over $\pmb D$. Note that a morphism $\varphi : \Gamma' \to \Gamma$ in this category is nothing else than a morphism $\varphi : \pmb a(\Gamma') \to \pmb a(\Gamma)$ between the apexes such that $\Gamma \circ \varphi = \Gamma'$. Of course not *every* morphism $\varphi : \pmb a(\Gamma') \to \pmb a(\Gamma)$ need to have this property. For the hom-sets we have therefore
$$\mathfrak{Cone}_{\pmb D}(\Gamma', \Gamma) \subset \pmb C(\pmb a(\Gamma'),\pmb a(\Gamma)) .$$

The author does not mention that such a universal cone *may not exist*. Anyway, this does not matter, we can focus to diagrams having a universal cone which is denoted by $\text{Lim} \pmb D$. Usually the apex $\pmb a(\text{Lim} \pmb D)$ of this cone is also denoted by $\text{Lim} \pmb D$. This notation may cause confusion, we must look at the context to decide whether it has to be understood as a cone or as the apex of a cone. That $\text{Lim} \pmb D$ is a terminal object means that for each cone $\Gamma$ *there exists a unique morphism $\tau \in  \mathfrak{Cone}_{\pmb D}(\Gamma, \text{Lim} \pmb D)$ such that $\text{Lim} \pmb D \circ \tau = \Gamma$*. This is what the author calls the "special morphism". It is in fact a very special element of the hom-set $\pmb C(\pmb a(\Gamma),\pmb a(\text{Lim} \pmb D)) \supset \mathfrak{Cone}_{\pmb D}(\Gamma,  \text{Lim} \pmb D)$ - it is uniquely determined by the above universal property of terminal elements.

Thus, if $\pmb D$ has a universal cone $\text{Lim} \pmb D$, then by definition the hom-set $\pmb C(\pmb c,\pmb a(\text{Lim} \pmb D))$ can never be empty if $\pmb c$ is the apex of another cone. However, in general the hom-set has more than one element, but only one of them is a morphism of cones.

Comment: Isn't EVERY morphism from $C(c, \textbf{Lim}D)$ can be used as this special morphism since it just maps from $c$ to $\textbf{Lim}D$. And he actually mentions that there can be no natural transformation afterwards, but in terms of my questions I cannot understand how one functor from hom-set factorizes meanwhile others do not if there is multiple of them. Or there is as many natural transformations as functors? I feel like I'm missing something important, since both you and author just mention that there is unique morphism and others are unfit as it is plain fact like 2+2=4.

Comment: @Supremus I made an update.